# Time Series using numpy or pandas

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, time-series

I'm a beginner of Python related environment and I have problem with using time series data.

The below is my OHLC 1 minute data.

```
2011-11-01,9:00:00,248.50,248.95,248.20,248.70
2011-11-01,9:01:00,248.70,249.00,248.65,248.85
2011-11-01,9:02:00,248.90,249.25,248.70,249.15
...
2011-11-01,15:03:00,250.25,250.30,250.05,250.15
2011-11-01,15:04:00,250.15,250.60,250.10,250.60
2011-11-01,15:15:00,250.55,250.55,250.55,250.55
2011-11-02,9:00:00,245.55,246.25,245.40,245.80
2011-11-02,9:01:00,245.85,246.40,245.75,246.35
2011-11-02,9:02:00,246.30,246.45,245.75,245.80
2011-11-02,9:03:00,245.75,245.85,245.30,245.35
...
```

1. I'd like to extract the last "CLOSE" data per each row and convert data format like the following:

   ```
   2011-11-01, 248.70, 248.85, 249.15, ... 250.15, 250.60, 250.55
   2011-11-02, 245.80, 246.35, 245.80, ...
   ...
   ```
2. I'd like to calculate the highest Close value and it's time(minute) per EACH DAY like the following:

   ```
   2011-11-01, 10:23:03, 250.55
   2011-11-02, 11:02:36, 251.00
   ....
   ```

Any help would be very appreciated.

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Is this data in a file? Have you used data frames before?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the pandas library. In the case of your data you can get the max as:

```
import pandas as pd
# Read in the data and parse the first two columns as a
# date-time and set it as index
df = pd.read_csv('your_file', parse_dates=[[0,1]], index_col=0, header=None)
# get only the fifth column (close)
df = df[[5]]
# Resample to date frequency and get the max value for each day.
df.resample('D', how='max')
```

If you want to show also the times, keep them in your DataFrame as a column and pass a function that will determine the max close value and return that row:

```
>>> df = pd.read_csv('your_file', parse_dates=[[0,1]], index_col=0, header=None,
                     usecols=[0, 1, 5], names=['d', 't', 'close'])
>>> df['time'] = df.index
>>> df.resample('D', how=lambda group: group.iloc[group['close'].argmax()])
             close                time
d_t                             
2011-11-01  250.60 2011-11-01 15:04:00
2011-11-02  246.35 2011-11-02 09:01:00
```

And if you wan't a list of the prices per day then just do a groupby per day and return the list of all the prices from every group using the `apply` on the grouped object:

```
>>> df.groupby(lambda dt: dt.date()).apply(lambda group: list(group['close']))
2011-11-01    [248.7, 248.85, 249.15, 250.15, 250.6, 250.55]
2011-11-02                    [245.8, 246.35, 245.8, 245.35]
```

For more information take a look at the docs: [Time Series](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/timeseries.html)

*Update for the concrete data set:*

The problem with your data set is that you have some days without any data, so the function passed in as the resampler should handle those cases:

```
def func(group):
    if len(group) == 0:
        return None
    return group.iloc[group['close'].argmax()]
df.resample('D', how=func).dropna()
```

Comment: Thank you, Viktor. I have two more questions. 1. How can I get time when day-high close is shown ? 2. How can I get close values of each days and list those as row per each day ? (like my question no. 1)

Comment: Thank you very much, Viktor! You're very good at using python vector manipulation logic!

Comment: @ViktorKerkez When i rung the command 'df.resample('D', how=lambda group: group.iloc[group['close'].argmax()])', Python shows following error 'IndexError: index out of bounds'. But, it works when I change group['close'].argmax() as group['close'].max(). How can I fix this problem ?

Comment: @user1913171 `max` is doing completely different thing - it returns the maximal value. You need the `argmax`, which returns the position of the maximal value in the index. What version of pandas are you using? Also try `ix` instead of `iloc`.

Comment: @ViktorKerkez It seems that it's from another reason. Could you let me know your email address? Then I'll send you my data.

Comment: @user1913171 just upload it as a gist or to some file share site, or even public dropbox link, and I'll take a look.

Comment: @ViktorKerkez Here is link of data : https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6582277/raw/32eeaf1f99dc44c781e136ead2c33f5d68bf6dbd/gistfile1.txt

Comment: @user1913171 Ah you have some days without data... I updated the answer.